# BrowserRouter runs Before useEffect on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

My problem is that React will check first Routing for my page and afterwards is going to run `useEffect()` function. This gives me kind of a problem. What im doing is that i need `useEffect()` to run first in order to fetch *data* from **local storage**. That specific *data* "decides" in which page my application will redirect.

So that's the main **App.js**

```
function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({id:null,authorized:false});

  useEffect(() => {
    const aUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    if(aUser!=null){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(aUser));
      setUser(aUser);
    }
   
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>

          <Route exact path="/" render={ () => 
            !user.authorized ? <Login setUser={setUser} user={user}/> 
            : <Redirect to="/home" />  }
                />

          <Route exact path="/login" render={ () =>
             !user.authorized ? <Login setUser={setUser} user={user}/> 
              : null}/>

          <Route exact path="/home" 
            render={() => !user.authorized ?
              <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Forbidden/>
            }/>
      
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So let's assume that *user* data is already stored in *local storage* and the user *is authorized*. When i start up my react app it will first show the *Home page* and that's because i have set the **Route "/"** to redirect to **"/home"** if the user is authorized. Ok that good.
My "problem" is when i **refresh** the page from */home* it will redirect to **/login**.
Why? Because **Routes will be checked first** and after that the `useEffect()` will run.

An obvious solution will be to redirect to */home* as i do for the first `Route` ("/").
OK i get that but why `useEffect()` Won't run first? That's my main question.

**Update:**

I can solve MY problem from the beginning but i want to know if there is a solution regarding `useEffect()`.
**One solution** is as i said before to redirect to "/home" if *user is authorized* like that

```
<Route exact path="/login" render={ () =>
             !user.authorized ? <Login setUser={setUser} user={user}/> 
              : <Redirect to="/home" /> 
       }
    />
```

Basically the same code as "/" Route.

**Another** solution that may be the best it's to get rid of `useEffect()` and load the *user data* with `useState()` like this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(()=>localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

Comment: You could add a state property to see if it's loading or it's done, if it's loading show null otherwise show a component.

Comment: What happens if you add to the dependency array: `[aUser]` ?

Comment: https://daveceddia.com/react-hook-after-render/#:~:text=Can%20you%20run%20a%20hook,only%20ever%20runs%20after%20render.

Comment: @Magofoco it sets the ```user``` variable from local storage. It's the same "object" but i load it from the local storage. After the ```setUser()``` occurs, ```user.authorized``` is ```true```. But the ```setUser()``` will run after the page has gone to /login route

Answer (score 3):

The way you can solve this problem is by initializing the state itself by fetching from local storage like this:

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState(()=>localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

useState takes a function that can be used to initialize the state. This is used for lazy intialization.

[Link to Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

It's also good to keep in mind the order in which the different lifecycle hooks run.

Comment: It's maybe the best solution but im gonna leave it unanswered. cause i wanna know if there is a solution with ```useEffect()```. It may be helpful for others

Comment: Hi, I think its important to keep in mind the hooks flow diagram https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow. useEffect is the last hook to run after the browser has already been painted which is why you are facing the issue. The lazy initializer is the first hook to run. Good to see alternate solutions though